How do I export a darts' TCNModel to ONNX?
I have a TCNModel that is trained on a time series:
model_air = TCNModel(
        input_chunk_length=13,
        output_chunk_length=12,
        n_epochs=3,
        dropout=0.1,
        dilation_base=2,
        weight_norm=True,
        kernel_size=5,
        num_filters=3,
        random_state=0,
        save_checkpoints=True,
        model_name=model_name,
        force_reset=True,
    )

According to darts documentation, the inner model_air.model of type darts.models.forecasting.tcn_model._TCNModule (derived from PLPastCovariatesModule) can be serialized to ONNX via to_onnx call. However, no matter what I try, I get errors at export:

model_air.model.to_onnx('model_air.onnx')

ValueError: Could not export to ONNX since neither input_sample nor model.example_input_array attribute is set.
dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 13, 1)
model_air.model.to_onnx('model_air.onnx', input_sample=dummy_input)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
dummy_input = (torch.randn(1, 13, 1), None)
model_air.model.to_onnx('model_air.onnx', input_sample=dummy_input)

TypeError: _TCNModule.forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
What input value should I give to model_air.model?

It appears that you're experiencing problems exporting your TCNModel to ONNX. The error messages indicate that you must provide an input sample when calling 'to_onnx', yet the model's 'forward' method does not allow very many inputs.
Have you checked the 'forward' method of your '_TCNModule' to see what the intended signature is? You may need to change it or write a new function to prepare the input for ONNX export.
Additionally, it may be beneficial to provide more information about your model's architecture and the type of data it processes. That could help us better understand the problem you're experiencing.

Hi @slope game, thanks for reply. The script is the one from https://github.com/unit8co/darts/blob/master/examples/05-TCN-examples.ipynb, with onnx export code added locally. Yes, stepped down to the forward method which throws the error - it expects a tuple (or list) of (at least) two elements, and the first one is forwarded through the network.

The answer/workaround I got from https://github.com/unit8co/darts/issues/2617 is helpful.
